# What kind of format should I use for a list to synchronize files?

Tags: xml, resources, synchronization, format

I am making a mobile app that syncs resources with a server. It will have the following behavior:

- There is a list of all of the files on the server
- There is a value where the remote files will be stored locally
- There is a checksum to compare with the local list to see whether the remote file has changed
- Preferably, the file should be encrypted. (But of course we can use https)

I first thought of the easiest solution, using a `CSV` to store values. Then we considered the extensibility of the program, and concluded that `XML` would be more open. I did some googling and did not find a schema that fits our purpose. `RSS`, `ATOM` falls short on some of our requirements, and `XDI` looks too complicated.

Should we make our own XML schema? Or is there some simple and default format that will fit our case.

Thanks!

**Answer**

I made a custom xml schema for this, here it is for anyone else to reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<!--Simple Types-->
<xs:simpleType name="remoteurltype">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:anyURI">
    <xs:pattern value="http(s)?://.*"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="localurltype">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:anyURI">
    <xs:pattern value="/.*"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="dectype">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
    <xs:pattern value="[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="hashtype">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:pattern value="[a-z0-9]{32}"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<!-- Complex Types -->
<xs:complexType name="resourcetype">
  <xs:attribute name="src" type="remoteurltype" use="required"/>
  <xs:attribute name="local" type="localurltype" use="required"/>
  <xs:attribute name="hash" type="hashtype" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="resourcelisttype">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="db" type="resourcetype"/>
    <xs:element name="img" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="resourcetype"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="version" type="dectype" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>

<!-- Root Element -->
<xs:element name="resources" type="resourcelisttype"/>

</xs:schema>
```

It is well validated and here is an example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<resources version="0.5"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="resources.xsd">
  <db src="http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/souptonuts/sqlite_examples.tar.gz?download"
    local="/database/default.sqlite" hash="64846a8f75d56fd68b01f55495ac5986" />
  <img src="http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png"
    local="/images/google.png" hash="4b9606a40bd81e8a047d2f74fa167e35" />
  <img src="http://www.baidu.com/img/baidu_sylogo1.gif"
    local="/images/baidu_sylogo1.gif" hash="52137eafacaf179057c837dfa720ecf9" />
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use your own XML schema for this. The ease with which new schema can be designed and implemented is probably the main advantage of using XML.

Stay away from CSV as it will be a source of constant problems with character sets, embedded quotes, embedded new lines etc.